# Global keyboard hook does not get specific characters

Tags: delphi, keyboard-hook

I recently found a sample code for global keyboard hooks and decided to study it. It is the same old code described here [Windows Global Keyboard Hook - Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156418/windows-global-keyboard-hook-delphi).

It works fine for basic latin characters but in some languages the user has to press a key and after that the desired letter key to get the special character. For example in Greek language the character ά is produced by pressing the ; key and then the α key. The hook will allow only the character α. I found out that pressing the keys in rapid succession works.

Is there a possible workaround to fix this minor issue?
Thanks in advance.

The code I use:

```
library HkT;

uses
  Windows,
  Messages,
  SysUtils,
  Classes;

{$R *.RES}

type
  PHookRec = ^THookRec;
  THookRec = record
    //AppHnd: Integer;
    MemoHnd: Integer;
  end;

var
  Hooked: Boolean;
  hKeyHook, hMemo, hMemFile: HWND;//, hApp: HWND;
  PHookRec1: PHookRec;

function KeyHookFunc(Code, VirtualKey, KeyStroke: Integer): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  KeyState1: TKeyBoardState;
  AryChar: array[0..1] of Char;
  Count: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if Code = HC_NOREMOVE then Exit;
  Result := CallNextHookEx(hKeyHook, Code, VirtualKey, KeyStroke);
  {I moved the CallNextHookEx up here but if you want to block
   or change any keys then move it back down}
  if Code < 0 then
    Exit;

  if Code = HC_ACTION then
  begin
    if ((KeyStroke and (1 shl 30)) <> 0) then
      if not IsWindow(hMemo) then
      begin
       {I moved the OpenFileMapping up here so it would not be opened
        unless the app the DLL is attatched to gets some Key messages}
        hMemFile  := OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_WRITE, False, 'Global7v9k');
        PHookRec1 := MapViewOfFile(hMemFile, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
        if PHookRec1 <> nil then
        begin
          hMemo := PHookRec1.MemoHnd;
          //hApp  := PHookRec1.AppHnd;
        end;
      end;
    if ((KeyStroke and (1 shl 30)) <> 0) then
    begin
      GetKeyboardState(KeyState1);
      Count := ToAscii(VirtualKey, KeyStroke, KeyState1, AryChar, 0);
      if Count = 1 then
      begin
        case VirtualKey of
          VK_DELETE: begin
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('['), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('D'), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('L'), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord(']'), 0);
          end;
          VK_BACK: begin
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('['), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('B'), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('S'), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord(']'), 0);
          end;
          VK_TAB: begin
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('['), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('T'), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('B'), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord(']'), 0);
          end;
          VK_RETURN: begin
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('['), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('E'), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('N'), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord(']'), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord(AryChar[0]), 0);
          end;
          VK_LSHIFT, VK_RSHIFT: begin
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('['), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('S'), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('F'), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord(']'), 0);
          end;
          VK_ESCAPE: begin
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('['), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('E'), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('S'), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord(']'), 0);
          end;
          VK_LCONTROL, VK_RCONTROL: begin
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('['), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('C'), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('T'), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord(']'), 0);
          end;
          VK_MENU: begin
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('['), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('A'), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord('L'), 0);
            SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord(']'), 0);
          end;
        else
          SendMessage(hMemo, WM_CHAR, Ord(AryChar[0]), 0);
          {I included 2 ways to get the Charaters, a Memo Hnadle and
           a WM_USER+1678 message to the program}
//          PostMessage(hApp, WM_USER + 1678, Ord(AryChar[0]), 0);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;


function StartHook(MemoHandle, AppHandle: HWND): Byte; export;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if Hooked then
  begin
    Result := 1;
    Exit;
  end;
  if not IsWindow(MemoHandle) then
  begin
    Result := 4;
    Exit;
  end;
  hKeyHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, KeyHookFunc, hInstance, 0);
  if hKeyHook > 0 then
  begin
    {you need to use a mapped file because this DLL attatches to every app
     that gets windows messages when it's hooked, and you can't get info except
     through a Globally avaiable Mapped file}
    hMemFile := CreateFileMapping($FFFFFFFF, // $FFFFFFFF gets a page memory file
      nil,                // no security attributes
      PAGE_READWRITE,     // read/write access
      0,                  // size: high 32-bits
      SizeOf(THookRec),   // size: low 32-bits
      //SizeOf(Integer),
      'Global7v9k');    // name of map object
    PHookRec1 := MapViewOfFile(hMemFile, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
    hMemo := MemoHandle;
    PHookRec1.MemoHnd := MemoHandle;
    //hApp := AppHandle;
    //PHookRec1.AppHnd := AppHandle;
    {set the Memo and App handles to the mapped file}
    Hooked := True;
  end
  else
    Result := 2;
end;

function StopHook: Boolean; export;
begin
  if PHookRec1 <> nil then
  begin
    UnmapViewOfFile(PHookRec1);
    CloseHandle(hMemFile);
    PHookRec1 := nil;
  end;
  if Hooked then
    Result := UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKeyHook)
  else
    Result := True;
  Hooked := False;
end;

procedure EntryProc(dwReason: DWORD);
begin
  if (dwReason = Dll_Process_Detach) then
  begin
    if PHookRec1 <> nil then
    begin
      UnmapViewOfFile(PHookRec1);
      CloseHandle(hMemFile);
    end;
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKeyHook);
  end;
end;

exports
  StartHook,
  StopHook;

begin
  PHookRec1 := nil;
  Hooked := False;
  hKeyHook := 0;
  hMemo := 0;
  DLLProc := @EntryProc;
  EntryProc(Dll_Process_Attach);
end.
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks. How does this code attempt to deal with Unicode. Why does it call ToAscii.

Comment: It seems that this code checks the existance of a key by calling ToAscii and it also translates the key? It does not deal with the Unicode. The captured char is returned with the ord command.

Comment: These characters are formed by multiple keystrokes. Your code doesn't account for that. You also don't appear to make any attempt to handle Unicode. My guess is that you copied this code but don't really understand it. Or understand keyboard input. Which is fiendishly complex. I know I don't understand it. I suggest a period of reading and learning is your next step.

Comment: Thnak you for your reply and your time.